# How can I fn:join Objects implementing toString in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl, seam

I'm iterating a list of entities in a table. This entity has a list of objects that override the `toString` method to provide the "name" property of their instance. Let's call them `B` objects.

In that table, I want to have a column where all values, as determined by calling their `toString` method, of object `B` are joined by a comma. Just like in this snippet:

```
<rich:column visible="false" label="function">
  <f:facet name="header">Function</f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{fn:join(a.b, ', ')}" />
</rich:column>
```

Where `b` is the List of objects of class `B`. Only problem is jsp1.2 won't render this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot convert [] of type class org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag to class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

So the question is: is there a nice way of handling this, short of a `<c:forEach>` to output the list values in a loop?

I'm afraid this is a legacy project using jsp1.2 and seam2.2 and I'm not allowed to upgrade that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a getter returning a `String` of your list:

```
public String getMyListAsString(){
  return org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(myList, ", ");
}
```

You can use the getter in EL:

```
#{myBean.myListAsString}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up with, yes (although I used Guava's Joiner instead of Apache's). Thanks!